# matplotlib - change marker color along plot line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot a 2d data set with matplotlib such that the marker color for each data point is different. I found the example on multicolored lines (http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html). However, this does not seem to work when plotting a line with markers.

The solution I came up with individually plots every point:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# The data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)

# The colormap
cmap = cm.jet

# Create figure and axes
fig = plt.figure(1)
fig.clf()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# Plot every single point with different color
for i in range(len(x)):
    c = cmap(int(np.rint(x[i] / x.max() * 255)))
    ax.plot(x[i], y[i], 'o', mfc=c, mec=c)
    ax.set_xlim([x[0], x[-1]])
    ax.set_ylim([-1.1, 1.1])
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')

plt.draw()
plt.show()

# Save the figure
fig.savefig('changing_marker_color.png', dpi=80)
```

The resulting plot looks like as it should but the plotting gets really slow and I need it quite fast. Is there a clever trick to speed up the plotting?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this with `ax.scatter`:

```
# The data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)

# The colormap
cmap = cm.jet

# Create figure and axes
fig = plt.figure(1)
fig.clf()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

c = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
ax.scatter(x, y, c=c, cmap=cmap)
```

Scatter accepts c as a sequence of floats which will be mapped to colors using the cmap.

[image]

Using `timeit` I get a 10 fold decrease in time (about 1.25 secs for the original method and 76.8 ms here)